# R language - t.test: Not enought 'x' observations

Tags: r

Hei,

I have a table in R with the following format

---

### Amino acids | Tag | ratio 1 | ratio 2

And to this table I want to apply the following function to add a t.test values for each row

```
table<- apply(table , 1,function(x) {

i <- as.numeric(x[3])
j <- as.numeric(x[4])

#Perform t.test
if( !is.na(i) && !is.na(j)){
test <- t.test( i, j, paired = TRUE)

out <- data.frame("Amino acids" = colnames(r)[r[1]],
                  "Tag" = colnames(r)[r[2]],
                  "LRatio 1" = colnames(r)[r[3]],
                  "LRatio 2" = colnames(r)[r[4]],
                  "Tvalue" = sprintf("%.3f", test$statistic),
                  "df" = test$parameter,
                  "Pvalue" = sprintf("%.3f", test$p.value))
return (out)
}
out <- data.frame("Amino acids" = colnames(r)[r[1]],
                "Tag" = colnames(r)[r[2]],
                "LRatio 1" = colnames(r)[r[3]],
                "LRatio 2" = colnames(r)[r[4]],
                "Tvalue" = "NA",
                "df" = "NA",
                "Pvalue" = "NA")  
return (out)
})
```

My t.test method tho , complains that I "do not have enough 'x' observations"

When debugging an example of values that I have is:

```
i: -0.2480872

j: -0.1382415

x: merged.ac
A0A075B5K6, A0A0B4J1H6, P01629, P01630, P03976

merged.r2
127

merged.lratio.x
-0.2480872152

merged.lratio.y
-1.382415e-01
```

Comment: You don't need a t-test to know if a single value is greater than another value. The t-test requires some estimation of variability, if you don't have at least two values in each group how can you estimate variability?

Comment: Maybe you want to run a single t-test between two columns of the dataframe rather than trying to do row-by-row t-tests of single numbers (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: Actually, I should run the t-test for 6 values for each peptide from each column. But that's a different issue I guess.

Comment: Statistics part aside for now, I'm looking for the error solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that t.test method takes as parameters two non-empty numeric vectors. In the code above, i and j are numeric values, thus the error of insuficient x values.